# How to use custom fonts and background image in OptionMenu

Tags: android

I am creating an option menu in my app. Now I want to use my custom font in the text that is displayed in the option menu and also want to set a custom background image. But I don't find any clue for that. The code I have used in creating the option menu is given below.

**XML file**

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item android:id="@+id/settingOpt" android:title="@string/opt_menu_txt1"
    android:icon="@drawable/icon_settings" />

<item android:id="@+id/reminderOpt" android:title="@string/opt_menu_txt2"
    android:icon="@drawable/icon_settings" />

<item android:id="@+id/helpOpt" android:title="@string/opt_menu_txt3"
    android:icon="@drawable/icon_settings" />

<item android:id="@+id/shareOpt" android:title="@string/opt_menu_txt4"
    android:icon="@drawable/icon_settings" />
```

**Code in java**

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
{                   
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
    return true;
}

public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
{   
            
    switch (item.getItemId()) 
    {
        case R.id.settingOpt:                           
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, SettingsForm.class);
            this.startActivity(intent);  
        break;         
            
        case R.id.reminderOpt:                          
            Intent intentR = new Intent(this, ReminderForm.class);
            this.startActivity(intentR);   
        break;
             
        case R.id.helpOpt:                          
            Intent intentH = new Intent(this, HelpForm.class);
            this.startActivity(intentH);                                    
        break;
             
        case R.id.shareOpt:                             
            Intent share = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            share.setType("text/plain");
            share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Name of the thing to share");
            share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "www.gmail.com");
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "Share LoveCycle's website link with your friends"));
        break;
        
        default:
            
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);       
    }
    
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution is provided [here](http://www.techjini.com/blog/2011/04/19/customizing-background-and-text-color-in-options-menu-android/) . But it does not seem to be a great way to do it.

Try the following:

```
@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // TODO :create the menu
        MenuInflater inflator = getMenuInflater();
        inflator.inflate(R.menu.home_screen_menu, menu);
        setMenuBackground();
        return true;
    }
```

The following will just change the background :

```
protected void setMenuBackground() {

        // Log.d(TAG, "Enterting setMenuBackGround");
        getLayoutInflater().setFactory(new Factory() {

            @Override
            public View onCreateView(String name, Context context,
                    AttributeSet attrs) {

                if (name.equalsIgnoreCase("com.android.internal.view.menu.IconMenuItemView")) {

                    try { // Ask our inflater to create the view
                        LayoutInflater f = getLayoutInflater();
                        final View view = f.createView(name, null, attrs);
                        /*
                         * The background gets refreshed each time a new item is
                         * added the options menu. So each time Android applies
                         * the default background we need to set our own
                         * background. This is done using a thread giving the
                         * background change as runnable object
                         */
                        new Handler().post(new Runnable() {
                            public void run() {
                                view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.menu_bg);
                            }
                        });
                        return view;
                    } catch (InflateException e) {
                    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                    }
                }
                return null;
            }
        });
    }
```

I define menu_bg in drawable folder as :

```
<xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 



android:shape="rectangle"> 

 <gradient
  android:startColor="#AA000000"    
  android:endColor="#AA000000"
  android:angle="90"/> 
</shape>
```

to google android developers : please provide an easier way to do this!.

Comment: i have tried a lot but cant suceed..can u please edited in  my code

Comment: i have edited my answer to include code example. Hope this helps.

Comment: i have implemented the code as it is..now is running but it doesnt show any effect in option menu

Comment: and one more thing if i want to put my own image as a background image in option menu what should i do

Comment: i just gave an exmaple of a gradient drawable here. You can reference any drawable that you want, possibly your own image. Not sure why it did not work for you, worked for me without too much fuss.

Comment: How to use my own image inside this xml file..can u show me with simple example

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5193/discussion-between-rdroid-and-anshuman)

Answer (score 1):

Android does't support customization for option menu. If you want't it, just create a custom view and inflate those view by overriding onCreateOptionMenu() method

Comment: Can you please help me with an examples

Comment: Create a layout in xml file with desired contents . use layout inflater  to inflate those view ‘s  when menu button is clicked.The method is shown below
@Override
 public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu){
  super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);

// Your inflation works here
}

Work with a flag to toggle the visibility of the menu and add some animations if needed

Answer (score 0):

[here](http://www.android10.org/index.php/forums/43-view-layout-a-resource/195-customizing-the-options-menu-background) is sample code that customize Option Menu Background, Hope this help you in some way.

Answer (score -3):

For custom fonts:
place the TTF file in the ./assets directory (create it if it doesn’t exist yet).

Create a layout as:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>  
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"  
          android:orientation="vertical"  
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"  
          android:layout_height="fill_parent"  
    >  

<TextView  
        android:id="@+id/custom_font"  
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"  
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
        android:text="This is the Chantelli Antiqua font."  
        />
```

Open your Activity Class:

```
 TextView txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.custom_font);  
 Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "yourfontname.ttf");  
 txt.setTypeface(font);
```